# yii2 ckeditor custom plugins

Tags: ckeditor, yii2

I'm using [2amigos ckeditor plugins](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget) in yii2, I was able to create a sample plugins from [plugin_sdk_sample](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample), it works fine in a raw project, but when I put that in a yii2 project, the button doesn't appear.

I put the custom plugin in \vendor\2amigos\yii2-ckeditor-widget\src\assets\ckeditor\plugins\ with plugin.js and png icon with the folder structure as described in the guide. I think the problem is with adding it to config.

I tried following in vendor\2amigos\yii2-ckeditor-widget\src\assets\ckeditor\config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
};
```

also tried the following in view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                        'clientOptions' => ['config.extraPlugins' => 'timestamp'],
                        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
                        'preset' => 'basic'
                    ]) ?>
```

but none of them seems to work and showing the button, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: thanks for improving the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add plugin.js into the list of script in

```
class CKEditorAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $js = [
        'ckeditor.js',
        'plugin.js',
        'adapters/jquery.js'
    ];
```

Comment: config.js instead of plugin.js worked for me, and i had to remove the asset directory to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
                'options' => ['rows' => 6],
                'preset' => 'custom',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    
                    'extraPlugins' => 'timestamp',
                    
                ]
                
            ]) ?>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are often not too clear. Could you please add some kind of commentary/explanation? Also, the formatting doesn't look great. Could you please edit your answer and improve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also customize the yii2 plugin toolbars like mentioned in below url-

[dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor custom toolbar](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/issues/37)

Answer (score -1):

I tried this in the file 
"vendor/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget/src/CKEditorAsset.php"

public $sourcePath = '@bower/adminlte/plugins/ckeditor';